# oracle adf how to invisible current row?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have oradcle adf and jdeveloper.
I want to invisible current row in a table by click on a button(named "delete_row") .
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Please tell us your exact Jdev version! Can you elaborate on the use case? What do you mean by 'invisible' should the row be visible again? When?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a soft delete of rows from table. Refer to this post [Soft deletion of rows](http://www.jobinesh.com/2011/05/soft-deletion-of-rows.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the row invisible but once you open again the application it will show again as this information is not stored anywhere. Better you have to override the remove operation for the current row. Once the remove operation is called you should change the value of a column from the table (boolean deleted for example). The query used in VO iterator for that table should not get rows with that value as false. Please check: http://husaindalal.blogspot.com/2009/11/generic-way-to-handle-soft-delete.html